# PHP/SQL Insert data from form and insert data from another table using prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to create a sale on a website I'm creating (Think of ebay), the user enters all the input details to create the sell able item, clicks the button and all the info inserts into the db table 'sellingitems' using a prepared statement, now the problem I have is I'm trying to get the users location (State & Suburb) details out of a table (user) and insert that with the prepared statement which all goes into "sellingitems" using SaleState, SaleSuburb in the sellingitems table, the error I get is

"  Fatal error: Statement failed! You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO sellingitems (ItemID, UserID, CatID, ItemName, ItemDesc, ItemAmount,' at line 2 in  "

I hope this is clear and understandable, I have researched for many hours and cannot find anything on INSERT with a join or some other means to help me, please ask if I need to clarify anything and thank you in advance for helping!!

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO sellingitems (ItemID, UserID, CatID, ItemName, ItemDesc, ItemAmount, TimeFrame, ItemCond, Postage, Returns, SaleState, SaleSuburb)
    SELECT State, Suburb FROM user WHERE UserID = '$UID' 
    VALUES ('',?,'',?,?,?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,?,?,?,State,Suburb)");

if ($stmt === false) {
trigger_error('Statement failed! ' . htmlspecialchars(mysqli_error($conn)), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$bind = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'issdsssss', $UID, $ItemName, $ItemDesc, $Amount, $ItemCond, $Postage, $Returns);

if ($bind === false) {
trigger_error('Bind param failed!', E_USER_ERROR);
}

$exec = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

if ($exec === false) {
trigger_error('Statement execute failed! ' . htmlspecialchars(mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)), E_USER_ERROR); 
}


if ($stmt == false) {
    $response = "Sorry something went wrong. : ";
    print_r($response);
    print_r($stmt->mysqli_error);
    print_r($stmt->error);
    return;

} else {
    $response = "Sale Created.";
    print_r($response);
}
```

Comment: Well, that SQL statement isn't valid, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not the correct syntax for an INSERT SELECT. [See the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html).

Try this instead:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO sellingitems (ItemID, UserID, CatID, ItemName, ItemDesc, ItemAmount, TimeFrame, ItemCond, Postage, Returns, SaleState, SaleSuburb)
    SELECT '',?,'',?,?,?, NOW(),?,?,?,State,Suburb FROM user WHERE UserID = '$UID'");
```

Better still would be to separate the two statements as in the following:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT State, Suburb FROM user WHERE UserID = '$UID'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$stmt = mysqli_prepare(
    $conn, 
    "INSERT INTO sellingitems (
        ItemID, 
        UserID, 
        CatID, 
        ItemName, 
        ItemDesc, 
        ItemAmount, 
        TimeFrame, 
        ItemCond, 
        Postage, 
        Returns, 
        SaleState, 
        SaleSuburb)
     VALUES
     ('', ?, '', ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?, ?, ?, '{$row['State']}', '{$row['Suburb']}')"
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your second option works like a charm!

Comment: The first option works well also :-), Thanks again!!

Comment: I want to upvote and make answered but it's says I need 15 more reputation points :-( Sorry dlporter98

Comment: Your should be able to accept the answer without also up voting